# 'Unique count' on reports is counting blank values

Tags: apex, lightning, reporting

I'm using the 'Unique' formula for a summary on a report, but the figure returned is wrong becuase it is to be counting the blank value as a unique value.

Is there a way to correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct this you need to add null check condition in the regular report filter condition for the respective field.

For example,

If you want to check unique count based on `FirstName` field on the contact object report then you need filter the contacts with `FirstName !=Null` in the regular filter condition.

Refer the below screenshot without null check condition for `Firstname` field.

[image]

Refer the below screenshot with null check condition for `Firstname` field.

[image]